# Appropriate use of spring redirect strategy

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I have a web-app that is secured behind CAS that periodically re authenticates. I have Users that can only access one section of the site and Admins can access the entire site. Would using a redirect strategy to force the user to the section that they can access and redirecting the admins to a page to where they can choose to either go to the admin page or user page be a correct use of the redirect strategy or would using another technology like spring web-flow be more appropriate?  It seems like the web-flow is a bit overkill but i'm not sure if the redirect strategy is fully appropriate.

Comment: I think you are right, this is not the usecase of spring web-flow. Some normal spring controllers that redirect, or a customized spring security redirect strategy will do the job.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it isn't a use-case of web-flow?

Comment: It is to small for web-flow. You can do it with much less effort when you do it by hand. The other point is, that I would try to plug it into spring-security.

Comment: I think using spring security makes a lot of sense here. with 2 very different roles that have access to different parts of the site. It would be fairly easy to redirect each one to the appropriate section